# CSS alignment issue using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am facing alignment issues using **bootstrap CSS**.

I want it like this:

**Place name:  dropdownbox**

**Gender**

**(radio-button)Male    (radio-button)Female**

**Amount**

**Max:  textbox    Min:  textbox**

How do I do it?

Comment: see my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-group" style="">
    <label _ngcontent-c0="" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="col-xs-6" style="display: flex;">
        <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="radio"><label _ngcontent-c0="">
            <input _ngcontent-c0="" name="gender" value="male" type="radio"> Male </label>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="radio">
            <label _ngcontent-c0=""><input _ngcontent-c0="" name="gender" value="female" type="radio"> Female </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added `display: flex;` to:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="col-xs-6" style="display: flex;">
```

This works. However, you would be better off giving this a class (other than col-xs-6) and doing the `display: flex;` within your CSS file.

You will then need to add either `margin-left` or `margin-right` to one of the buttons to give it space.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's you updated code:

```html
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container">

 <form [formGroup]="form" class="">

  <div class="row padding-top-xl">
   <div class="col-sm-8">

    <form id="basicBootstrapForm" class="form-horizontal">

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-3 control-label">Place Name</label>
        <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control">
            <option>USA</option>
              <option>UK</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-3 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="radio col-6">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio col-6">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
                </label>
            </div>
            
          </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
    
       <div class="form-group">
        <p>Amount</p> 
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-2 control-label">Max</label>
          <div class="col-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName"/>
          </div>
          <label class="col-2 control-label">Min</label>
          <div class="col-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName"/>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
 
</form>
 
  </div> 

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  </div>

 </div>

 
</form>
 
</div> 
  <appfooter></appfooter>
```

Because you are using Bootstrap 4 you can forget `col-xs-6`,  [the default is](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#grid-system) `col-6`:

> `xs` grid classes have been modified to not require the infix to more accurately represent that they start applying styles at `min-width: 0` and not a set pixel value. Instead of `.col-xs-6`, it’s now `.col-6`. All other grid tiers require the infix (e.g., `sm`).

Comment: Place name is not coming properly